# Routing error for no route matches when action is clearly in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actioncontroller

I think it is a routing issue where the controller is not matched properly.  I am confused because there is clearly a `new` action in my `ComicTitlesController`.

Here is the error I receive when I load the home page, which has the `new_user_comic_title_path` in the navbar:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comic_titles"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

In my views:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Publish' , new_user_comic_title_path %></li>
```

The `ComicTitles` controller:

```
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @comic_title = @user.comic_titles.new
  end
```

Note that `ComicTitle` is nested under `User`.  Here is the route file:

```
  resources :users, shallow: true do
    resources :comic_titles
  end
```

When I run `rake routes`:

```
 user_comic_titles GET    /users/:user_id/comic_titles(.:format)             comic_titles#index
                     POST   /users/:user_id/comic_titles(.:format)             comic_titles#create
new_user_comic_title GET    /users/:user_id/comic_titles/new(.:format)         comic_titles#new
    edit_comic_title GET    /comic_titles/:id/edit(.:format)                   comic_titles#edit
         comic_title GET    /comic_titles/:id(.:format)                        comic_titles#show
                     PUT    /comic_titles/:id(.:format)                        comic_titles#update
                     DELETE /comic_titles/:id(.:format)                        comic_titles#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a nested route, I believe the route is expecting a user_id parameter.

In your link_to helper try adding the following:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Publish' , new_user_comic_title_path(user_id: current_user.id) %></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the route requires parameter `:user_id` and your `link_to` is missing that parameter.

Try updating your `link_to` definition to following:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Publish' , new_user_comic_title_path(@user) %></li>
```

Comment: Thanks!  However now when I click on the link it gives me:

Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/users/1/2/comic_titles/new"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
Not sure why there is /1/2...